# sed to replace list of subnets at nth position in a file

Tags: shell, sed

Adding "ip","ip","ip" to each IP address

```
tf_alist=$(for i in $alist; do echo -n "\"$i\"",; done | sed 's/,$//')
echo $tf_alist
```

gives:

```
"192.168.0.216/29","192.168.92.72/30","192.168.92.70/31"
```

Now, I've `variable.tf` as shown below:

```
variable "allowlisted_cidrs_prod" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "ip ranges - allowlisted - prod instances"
  default     = ["192.168.241.88/32", "192.168.128.222/32", "192.168.231.150/32"]
}

variable "allowlisted_cidrs_test" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "ip ranges - allowlisted - test instances"
  default     = ["192.168.58.61/32", "192.168.3.224/32"]
}

variable "elb_cipher" {
  type        = string
  description = "ELB cipher"
  default     = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
}
```

At `variable "allowlisted_cidrs_prod"` I want to replace the below list string:

- From:

  `default     = ["192.168.241.88/32", "192.168.128.222/32", "192.168.231.150/32"]`
- To (as per `$tf_alist`):

  `default     = ["192.168.0.216/29","192.168.92.72/30","192.168.92.70/31"]`

can you suggest a way to do it using sed? TYA!

To replace the string, I'm trying to use the below expression to capture the existing IP list:

```
old_ip_list=$(cat variable.tf | sed -n '/variable "allowlisted_cidrs_prod"/,$ {/^[[:blank:]]*default[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*\(.*\).*/ { s//\1/p; q; }}')
```

gives:

```
["192.168.241.88/32", "192.168.128.222/32", "192.168.231.150/32"]
```

Ref: https://sed.js.org/?gist=bdeddb0ed01bdc8f96b3a05952909cd7

Removes "[]" from the given output to match with `$tf_alist`.

```
echo -e "\n $old_ip_list" | gsed 's/.*\[//;s/\].*//;'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to edit a structured format like this is to use a tool for that particular structured format. If this is code in a programming language, probably change the code to read the values from an external resource into a variable, and don't modify the code at all if you can avoid it.

Having said that, here is a quick refactoring.

```sh
tf_alist=$(printf ',"%s"' $alist | sed 's/^,//')

awk -v new="$tf_alist" '/^variable "/ { v=$2 }
    v=="\"allowlisted_cidrs_prod\"" && $1 == "default" { sub(/\[.*/, "[" new "]") }
    1' variable.tf >new_variable.tf
```

This simply keeps track of which `variable` it has last seen, and only replaces the `default` line when it's the one we are trying to target. The final `1` is a common Awk idiom to unconditionally print all lines. And of course `sub` is Awk's equivalent of the `s///` command in `sed`, and `"[" new "]"` is simple string concatenation; we put square brackets around the value of the variable `new` (which is defined in the `-v` option - it contains the value of the shell variable `$tf_alist`).

As all ad-hoc parsers, this is fairly brittle, but it works with the example you provided (demo: https://ideone.com/7kDNCU). If this is for more than a one-off, seriously think about a different approach, rather than spending more time on making this more robust (or, heavens, reimplementing it in read-only `sed`).

Comment: oh wow! this is next level to me. Thank you so much! I was testing `sed -i "s/$old_ip_list/$tf_alist/g"`, but your solution looks way better! could you also explain how awk script works, please?

Comment: Added a brief explanation. If you are completely unfamiliar with Awk, think of it as `sed`++ -- the basic processing model is quite similar.

Comment: i'm trying to understand how `new`  (in the context of `sub(regexp, replacement, target)`) works. Could you please elaborate or point me to some documentation?

Comment: `new` is just the name of the variable I defined in the `-v` option; the value is copied from the shell variable `tf_alist`. I specifically used a different variable name to highlight that the two are separate; Awk has no knowledge of your shell's variables, and vice versa.